# Why not throw an exception if [super init] returns nil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, exception, init

This is considered typical

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // <#initializations#>
    }
    return self;
}
```

but wouldn't it be better to go with something like this which actually responds appropriately?

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // <#initializations#>
    } else {
       @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:@"you think your constructor is executing, but it's not"] userInfo:nil]
    }
    return self;
}
```

The corollary to this question is, "under what conditions would `[super init]` return `nil` and **shouldn't you handle that in the `init` method?**"

Comment: If the initialization is a failure to the point that your app won't work anymore, best to simply crash.  I.e. call abort() or use `__builtin_trap` instead of `@throw`.  Throwing an exception is guaranteed to lose information about the failure.

Comment: Thanks @bbum for entertaining the question. Good points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason, why you should do, what JustSid is saying:

In object-orientated design you should always code, as if you maybe will hand your class over to another project by another developer. So you can't assume, that a failure in initialization in his project may be as bad as it is probably in yours. Maybe this developer is you in 5 years. Imagine your hassle to fix your 200 classes, you want to reuse.

Answer (score 10):

No, exceptions in Objective-C are meant for states which you can't really recover from, not just something to show that an operation failed. If you initializer fails, simply return nil to show it.

Comment: How can you possibly recover from the World not working the way it's supposed to. It's true that you COULD continue, but all subsequent code that's run would be meaningless, since your assumptions are blown.

Comment: @Yar: If you can't recover from something this simple you might want to reconsider your code.

Comment: @Yar: but ObjC is relatively unique in that quite a lot of the language is established by convention, not by syntax. That creates a presumption that certain patterns will be followed, and the test for avoiding a pattern becomes a very high threshold.

Comment: @JustSid, sorry, the idea is that you would have some actual code where  `// <#initializations#>` is. If it's just an empty section then you don't need the `if` whatsoever.

Comment: @Yar The point here is, if super's _-init_ returns _nil_ for some reason, which is a valid return value, you can skip a bunch of possibly costly initialization operations. Otherwise the fact that your _-init_ returns _nil_, communicates that it didn't fully (or at all) execute enough - you don't need an exception for that. On a side note, _-init_ is not a constructor but an initializer. This may seem like a merely semantic distinction but it is not.

Comment: @Lurch doesn't this mean that all of your code should be written to assume that the either 1) the inits didn't run, so they're "optional" or 2) that you get a nil return value when you call your `alloc-init` line and react accordingly? I've never seen code that defensive.

Comment: (Edited: you return nil, not NULL.)

Comment: @Yar Well, the short answer is, yes, you should code expecting _alloc/init_ (as well as _copy_ and just about anything else) to return _nil_. The longer answer is the unfortunately tautological -- you should care only if you care. If the state of your program absolutely depends on something not being _nil_ and you cannot at all recover it is OK to throw an exception, only you do it wherever it matters, e.g.: `MYBar* foo = [[MYBar alloc] initWithData:someData]; NSAssert(foo != nil, @"Can't continue like this.");`

Answer (score 10):

Not really.

with:

```
self = [super init];
```

you are calling your superclasses init method, which only in RARE cases will return nil. (like if the system has low memory, which you have other problems).

```
if(self)
```

this will not go through if no instance is returned (it is nil) so there is no need for the else.

the old way was

```
if((self = [super init))
{
    // do initialization
}
return self
```

EDIT: Was reading the Cocoa Fundementals guide and found this under Error Handling:

> If the error encountered in a method
>   implementation is a system-‐level or
>   Objective-‐C runtime error, create and
>   raise an exception, if necessary, and
>   handle it locally, if possible. In
>   Cocoa, exceptions are typically
>   reserved for programming or unexpected
>   runtime errors such as out-‐of-‐bounds
>   collection access, attempts to mutate
>   immutable objects, sending an invalid
>   message, and losing the connection to
>   the window server. You usually take
>   care of these errors with exceptions
>   when an application is being created
>   rather than at runtime. Cocoa
>   predefines several exceptions that you
>   can catch with an exception handler.
>   For information on predefined
>   exceptions and the procedure and API
>   for raising and handling exceptions,
>   see Exception Programming Topics.
>
> For other sorts of errors, including
>   expected runtime errors, return nil,
>   NO, NULL, or some other type-‐suitable
>   form of zero to the caller. Examples
>   of these errors include the inability
>   to read or write a file, a **failure to
>   initialize an object**, the inability to
>   establish a network connection, or a
>   failure to locate an object in a
>   collection. Use an NSError object if
>   you feel it necessary to return
>   supplemental information about the
>   error to the sender. An NSError object
>   encapsulates information about an
>   error, including an error code (which
>   can be specific to the Mach, POSIX, or
>   OSStatus domains) and a dictionary of
>   program-‐specific information. The
>   negative value that is directly
>   returned (nil, NO, and so on) should
>   be the principal indicator of error;
>   if you do communicate more specific
>   error information, return an NSError
>   object indirectly in a parameter of
>   the method.

Comment: Gunman, there in the middle you hit it on the head. "if the system has low memory"... wouldn't you want an Exception to be thrown there, which where the problem happened?

Comment: Could you not just log it in that case?

Comment: Your logger might have a problem too, in that case. It doesn't alloc-init objects?

Comment: Added the conventions (that apply to your question) to my answer from  the Error handling section of the Cocoa Fundamentals guide.

Comment: Thanks @Lone Gunman... which leads me to my next point. Does anybody actually check for `nil` after they call init? Generally not, and then if you call ANY property setter or getter using dot-notation on `nil`, your program blows up anyway.

Comment: Sending a message to nil doesn't crash your program, it does nothing.  I'm not sure if you are asking weather people actually use the if((self = [super init])); convention or doing some kind of nil check outside of the init method.  If the former, I'd say yes mainly because templates usually set that up for you ^^.

Answer (score 3):

Returning `nil` is the appropriate thing to do. Part of the reason that sending any message to nil is allowed and defined to return nil as a result is that you can build compound statements like:

```
resultObject = [[[[class alloc] init] autorelease] someProperty];
```

That statement executes all the way through even if any individual method call returns nil. To fit with that, the `init` convention is to return the nil if the superclass does so.

As JustSid points out, ObjC uses exceptions only for unrecoverable problems.