# Can I use assert() to catch failure of [super init]?

Tags: objective-c, assert, init, super

A typical `init` method in Objective C returns `nil` if initialisation fails:

```
- (id) init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    // more initialisation
  }
  return self;
}
```

Would it make sense to use assertions to catch initialisations which should
always succeed? i.e:

```
- (id) init {
  self = [super init];
  assert(self);  // unrecoverable?

  // more initialisation
  array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
  assert(array); // unrecoverable?

  return self;
}
```

In this case, failure of `[super init]` is defined (assumed?) to be an unrecoverable error, so crashing with an assertion failure is warranted.

It seems that the convention of returning `nil` is intended to be used to allow for error recovery, but in situations where error recovery isn't possible, is it reasonable to just throw an assertion?

Thanks...

Edit:

And see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574938/why-not-throw-an-exception-if-super-init-returns-nil)

Comment: No. Throw an exception then. Assertions are meant for asserting logically impossible/unreachable paths during debugging, and as such, they are turned off in a release build. They were never intended for error handling, so they are not reliable for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'd forgotten that assertions are often disabled in release builds.

Answer (score 1):

No returning `nil`, as per the normal pattern, is sufficient.  It's up to the caller to decide what to do about it:

```
id obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
if (!obj)
    [NSException raise:@"Oops"];
```

Comment: Thanks, @Droppy. Would this apply *within* an initialiser?

Comment: There are plenty of init methods where returning nil is (kind of) normal and doesn't justify throwing an exception.

Comment: @gnasher729 Which is why I say it's up to the caller.